# method contains in dictionnary of type text list string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dictionary with keys of type `Text` and values of type `List<string>` and I want to test if this dictionary contains a key with name = "U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE".

What I did is :

```
Dictionary<Text, List<string>> echancierURSSAFE = new Dictionary<Text, List<string>>();

var dictionaryPROVIS = new Dictionary<string, string>();

dictionaryPROVIS.Keys.Where(key => echancierURSSAFE.Contains("U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE")).ToList();
```

Here is `Text` class:

```
public class Text
{
    public String Titre { get; set; }
    public bool IsTitre { get; set; }

    public bool IsDesignation { get; set; }
}
```

Here I have an exception that this type of dictionary doesn't contain a method `contains`. So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's `Text` class?

Comment: You're probably looking for the `ContainsKey`. Never used the type `Text` what is it?

Comment: Do you want `key => echancierURSSAFE.Values.Any(l => l.Contains("U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE"))` basically searching all the lists in that dictionary?

Comment: @D-Shih i have added code of text class in the question

Comment: @juharr yes that's it

Comment: What's the connection between `dictionaryPROVIS` and `dictionaryPROVIS`?

Comment: That's only going to either match every key or none since you don't even use the key in the expression.  Maybe you mean `key => echancierURSSAFE.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Titre == key && kvp.Value.Contains("U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE")` which searches the list in the dictionary that has a `Text` key that has a `Titre` value that matches the key from the other dictionary?  It would be helpful if you could give examples of input data and expected output.

Comment: @D-Shih just i want to store the count of the condition in a variable dictionaryPROVIS  to know if count == 0 or no i mean if my dictionnary contain the  titre "U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE" or no

Comment: @juharr just i want to know if i have a text with titre value "U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment, you can try to use `Any` with `Titre`, which will check the `Dictionary` Text's `Titre` contain any `"U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE"`

```
echancierURSSAFE.Keys.Any(x => x.Titre == "U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE");
```

if you want to get all List you can use `Where`

```
echancierURSSAFE.Keys.Where(x => x.Titre == "U.R.P.S. PROVISIONNELLE");
```

Comment: But enumerating a dictionary to check if there is a key is inefficient. Why using a dictionary then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for your comment, but I am not sure your mean  `key is inefficient.` because I only know the `dictionary` time complexity is `O(1)` is there any link talk about your comment? I would like to take a look :)